# New cast exception with VS2010/.Net 4

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

[ Updated 25 May 2010 ]
I've recently upgraded from VS2008 to VS2010, and at the same time upgraded to .Net 4.

I've recompiled an existing solution of mine and I'm encountering a Cast exception I did not have before.

The structure of the code is simple (although the actual implementation somewhat more complicated).

Basically I have:

```
public class SomeClass : ISomeClass
{
 // Stuff
}

public static class ClassFactory
{
  public static IInterface GetClassInstance<IInterface>(Type classType)
  {
     return (IInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(classType); // This throws a cast exception
  }
}

// Call the factory with:

ISomeClass anInstance = ClassFactory.GetClassInstance<ISomeClass>(typeof(SomeClass));
```

Ignore the 'sensibleness' of the above - its provides just a representation of the issue rather than the specifics of what I'm doing (e.g. constructor parameters have been removed).

The marked line throws the exception:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'Namespace.SomeClass' to type
>   'Namespace.ISomeClass'.

I suspect it may have something to do with the additional DotNet security (and in particular, explicit loading of assemblies, as this is something my app does).

The reason I suspect this is that I have had to add to the config file the setting:

```
<runtime>
    <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />
</runtime>
```

.. but I'm unsure if this is related.

**Update**

I see (from comments) that my basic code does not reproduce the issue by itself. Not surprising I suppose. It's going to be tricky to identify which part of a largish 3-tier CQS system is relevant to this problem.

One issue might be that there are multiple assemblies involved. My static class is actually a factory provider, and the 'SomeClass' is a class factory (relevant in that the factories are 'registered' within the app via explicit assembly/type loading - see below) .

Upfront I use reflection to 'register' all factories (i.e. classes that implement a particular interface) and that I do this when the app starts by identifying the relevant assemblies, loading them and adding them to a cache using (in essence):

```
Loop over (file in files)
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(file);
    baseAssemblyList.Add(assembly);
}
```

Then I cache the available types in these assemblies with:

```
foreach (Assembly assembly in _loadedAssemblyList)
{
  Type[] assemblyTypes = assembly.GetTypes();
  _loadedTypesCache.AddRange(assemblyTypes);
}
```

And then I use this cache to do a variety of reflection operations, including 'registering' of factories, which involves looping through all loaded (cached) types and finding those that implement the (base) Factory interface.

I've experienced what may be a similar problem in the past (.Net 3.5, so not exactly the same) with an architecture that involved dynamically creating classes on the server and streaming the compiled binary of those classes to the client app. The problem came when trying to deserialize an instance of the dynamic class on the client from a remote call: the exception said the class type was not know, even though the source and destination types were exactly the same name (including namespace). Basically the cross boundry versions of the class were not recognised as being the same. I solved that by intercepting the deserialization process and explicitly defining the deseriazation class type in the context of the local assemblies.

This experience is what makes me think the types are considered mismatched because (somehow) the interface of the actual SomeClass object, and the interface of passed into the Generic method are not considered the same type.

So (possibly) my question for those more knowledgable about C#/DotNet is: How does the class loading work that somehow my app thinks there are two versions/types of the interface type and how can I fix that (keeping in mind its a DotNet 3.5 vs 4 issue as it worked before my upgrade) ?

[ whew ... anyone who got here is quite patient .. thanks ]

Comment: Check that you don't have two classes named `SomeClass`, but only one implements `ISomeClass`...

Comment: ... or there are two `ISomeClass` interfaces (in different assemblies).

Comment: Not explicitly. I've updated the main question with details but I do suspect DotNet thinks there are two types with exactly the same name (I'm guess it's the interface type), somehow caused by my explicit loading of assemblies and their types. Question is: How to avoid this?

Comment: Riiight. Oddly, the issue is intermittent. This suggested to me that it might be caused by a residual (pre DotNet upgrade/rebuild) DLL lying around in a BIN directory. I've deleted all such DLLs and run the app - with no error. But, as I said, the problem is intermittent so it may just be in remission.

Comment: Not solved. Still occurs intermittently, which is suspicious in its own right.

Comment: Some progress. I've established the following:
The issue appears to be related to the combination of the way I register factories (using explicit loading of assemblies and reflection of the classes therein) and the fact that this is happening within an ASP.Net server. The latter means that the DLLS are copied (when run from within VS) to a temp location (continued)

Comment: My Assembly load process attempts to detect 'shadow' copies of DLLs (using assembly references present in the current domain - method AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()). The idea is: Search for all relevant files (DLLs/EXEs) in the app directory and try to register them, BUT - If the Domain has the assembly listed I use that one (if not, I load the 'found in directory' assembly) ...
The problem is that the ASP.Net server application has some assemblies repeated in the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() list: And the dups are in different dirs (original and run-time temp)

Comment: So, to cut to the chase: sometimes when I establish the list of assemblies I use to load and register all Factory types I use the DLL in the original source (BIN) directory, and sometimes I end up using the DLL in the ASP.Net run-time temporary directory. In the former case this is a problem as the Interface type defined in the temp-directory DLL is not the "same" one that was registered by my cache process (as that comes from a different copy of the same assembly). So there are two Interfaces of the same name. Loaded from  different copies of the same assembly.

Comment: Sadly the problem is not solved, but seems to come down to the fact that sometimes the call to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() returns a list of DLLs that includes those in the ASP.Net temporary file location, and sometimes it does not. When it does not, the exception occurs. No idea why the difference.

Comment: If I do a full build before running, the GetAssemblies() list has both the source directory and the temp directory versions of the DLLs in it  (and my app works), if I don't do a full build (even if I make no code changes) and run the app a second time, the GetAssemblies() list only has the source directory DLL versions and the app throws an exception. Great.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes that it has something to do either with the runtime loading of assemblies, or with the upgrade conversion, I used this code in a new project and had no issues.  Can you provide more code to replicate the error?

Comment: Thanks for the effort :) [ Obviously I didn't try this exact code outside my real problem code ]

I'm about to add more info to the main post.

Answer (score 0):

The 'quick' (ITO implementation, not ITO finding it) solution was to stop the shadow copy of my app's DLLs.
This is done by modifying the ASP.Net app's Web.Config file as follows:

In section 'configuration/web.settings', add setting:

```
<hostingEnvironment shadowCopyBinAssemblies="false" />
```